# Apache Directory Studio GSSAPI (Kerberos) Error

Tags: java, apache, active-directory, ldap, domaincontroller

I would like to ask from all of you, that what should be the solution for my error message.
It is about, when I check the authentication with the server and the settings are set to: Use native TGT in Kerberos settings.

The authentication parameters:
Bind DN or user: admin (which is in domain)
Bind password: is my password.

The error message is:

```
The authentication failed. - java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
org.apace.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapException:
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed 
[Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided 
    (Mechanism level: Illegal key size)]
```

When I click on more details:

```
The authentication failed
 - java.security.PrivilegedActionException: org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Illegal key size)]
  org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Illegal key size)]
    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bindAsync(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1535)
    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bind(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1421)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper$2.run(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:447)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.runAndMonitor(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1175)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.doBind(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:460)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.bind(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:306)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.jobs.CheckBindRunnable.run(CheckBindRunnable.java:79)
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.ui.RunnableContextRunner$1.run(RunnableContextRunner.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Illegal key size)]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bindAsync(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1525)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Illegal key size)]
    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bindSasl(LdapNetworkConnection.java:3898)
    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.access$200(LdapNetworkConnection.java:178)
    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection$2.run(LdapNetworkConnection.java:1529)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Illegal key size)]
    at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.directory.ldap.client.api.LdapNetworkConnection.bindSasl(LdapNetworkConnection.java:3808)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Illegal key size)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(Unknown Source)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: KrbException: Illegal key size
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.encrypt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType.encrypt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.EncryptedData.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.createMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.createRequest(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbTgsReq.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.serviceCreds(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.CredentialsUtil.acquireServiceCreds(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.Credentials.acquireServiceCreds(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.getCipher(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.DkCrypto.dr(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.DkCrypto.dk(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.encryptCTS(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.dk.AesDkCrypto.encrypt(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256.encrypt(Unknown Source)
    ... 30 more

  java.security.PrivilegedActionException: org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.exception.LdapException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Illegal key size)]
```

Thanks for all your kind help.

P.S.: My set up is
Kerberos Real: My domain
KDC Host: My domain
KDC Port: 88

The Network parameter:

Name: Enterprise
Hostname: my domain
Port 389
Encryption: No encryption

Provider apache directory LDAP Client Api

Comment: In your manual retyping of the error messages you missed the most important word to understand your error: `size`. I fixed that for you.

Comment: Thank you :) I appreciate it